# Is there anything wrong with If/Elif structure?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

Two integers are set -100<=a,b<=100. Find their a + b, a - b, a * b, and a / b.

So I need to output four numbers (sum, difference, product, and quotient) separated by a space to Terminal. If I can't find the quotient, I need to print the symbol "#" instead of the quotient result. Everything is fine but when I input numbers that are not included in that interval, it doesn't output 'a or b out of range'. The first part is just not working...

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$1
b=$2
if [[ -100 -ge $a && $a -ge 100 ]] || [[ -100 -ge $b && $b -ge 100 ]]
then
    echo 'a or b out of range'
elif [[ $((a % b)) = 0 ]]
then
    echo $((a + b)) $((a - b)) $((a * b)) $((a / b))
else
    echo $((a + b)) $((a - b)) $((a * b)) '#'
fi
```

Comment: Check it with shellcheck.net

Comment: So actually you want a and be between -100 and 100, right?

Comment: I think you meant 'or' where you said 'and' with `&&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
if [[ -100 -ge $a && $a -ge 100 ]] || [[ -100 -ge $b && $b -ge 100 ]]
```

The problem is that you are looking for a number that must be lower **AND** bigger than the current range. That's not going to happen. You should change the conditions to be **OR**.

```sh
if [[ -100 -ge $a || $a -ge 100 ]] || [[ -100 -ge $b || $b -ge 100 ]]
```

Here you have the working script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
a=$1
b=$2
if [[ -100 -ge $a || $a -ge 100 ]] || [[ -100 -ge $b || $b -ge 100 ]]
then
    echo 'a or b out of range'
elif [[ $((a % b)) = 0 ]]
then
    echo $((a + b)) $((a - b)) $((a * b)) $((a / b))
else
    echo $((a + b)) $((a - b)) $((a * b)) '#'
fi
```